# NodeJS + MongoJS: Nested Callbacks Issue

Tags: node.js, mongojs

I'm still a n00b with NodeJS so this question may be somewhat elementary.

I'm using MongoJS to read two logically related collections. The first **find()** returns a value that I pass to the second **find()** to get the information I need.

I've tried several strategies, the last one (snippet #1) being a class that I export.

Before that I just had a function that did a **return**, returning the desired value, i.e., "config[0]".

In this code all I did was set the "sapConfig" attribute to the word "test", but when I execute this code the value of "sapConfig" is always "null" after I call the "get_config()" method and - strangest of all - the reference to "this.sapConfig = 'test'" generates an error, i.e., "Cannot set property 'sapConfig' of undefined".

When I had the code just as a simple function with a **return** statement (snippet #2), no errors were generated but the value returned is always "undefined" although the console.log() statements show that the value of the variable being returned has the desired value. What gives?

**Code Snippet #1: Returns Object**

```
"use strict";

var mongojs = require('mongojs'); // MongoDB API wrapper

module.exports = function(regKey) {

    this.regKey = regKey;
    this.sapConfig = null;

    this.get_config = function() {

        // Read SAP connection information from our MONGO db
        var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost/MIM', ['Configurations','Registrations']);

        db.Registrations.find({ key: this.regKey }, function(err1, registration){
            console.log('Reg.find()');
            console.log(registration[0]);
            db.Configurations.find({ type: registration[0].type }, function(err2, config){
                console.log('Config.find()');
                console.log('config=' + config[0].user);
                this.sapConfig = 'test';
            });
        });
    }

    this.get_result = function() {
        return this.sapConfig;
    }
}
```

Again, the code in snippet #1, when I make a call to "get_config()", results in an error when it executes the line "this.sapConfig = 'test'".

However, after this error I can execute "obj.get_result()" and I get the value to which it was initialized, i.e., null. In other words, that same code doesn't generate an error saying that the "this" is undefined as .in the "get_config()" method

Code Snippet #2: Using the "return" statement

```
"use strict";

var mongojs = require('mongojs'); // MongoDB API wrapper

module.exports = function(regKey) {

        // Read SAP connection information from our MONGO db
        var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost/MIM', ['Configurations','Registrations']);

        db.Registrations.find({ key: regKey }, function(err1, registration){
            console.log('Reg.find()');
            console.log(registration[0]);
            db.Configurations.find({ type: registration[0].type }, function(err2, config){
                console.log('Config.find()');
                console.log('config=' + config[0].user);
                return config[0].user;
            });
        });
}
```

When I receive the return value and inspect it, it's "undefined". For example, at the Node CL I issue the following commands:

```
var config = require('./config') // The name of the module above
> var k = config('2eac44bc-232d-4667-bd24-18e71879f18c')
undefined <-- this is from MongoJS; it's fine
> Reg.find() <-- debug statement in my function
{ _id: 589e2bf64b0e89f233da8fbb,
  key: '2eac44bc-232d-4667-bd24-18e71879f18c',
  type: 'TEST' }
Config.find()
config=MST0025
> k <-- this should have the value of "config[0]"
undefined
```

You can see that the queries were successful but the value of "k" is "undefined". What's going on here?

I don't care which approach I use I just need one of them to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my new example in my answer for the second part :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.sapConfig` is not accessible. Thats because `this` refers to within the current function. What I like todo, is have a variable that refers to the function instance that you know `sapConfig` is located in.

Ex:

```
function Foo() {
   var self = this;

   this.test = "I am test";

   var bar = function(){
     return function(){
       console.log(this.test); //outputs undefined (because this refers to the current function scope)
       console.log(self.test); //outputs "I am test";
     }
   }
}
```

Here is your first code snippit with my example implemented:

```
"use strict";

var mongojs = require('mongojs'); // MongoDB API wrapper

module.exports = function(regKey) {
  var self = this;

  this.regKey = regKey;
  this.sapConfig = null;

  this.get_config = function() {

    // Read SAP connection information from our MONGO db
    var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost/MIM', ['Configurations', 'Registrations']);

    db.Registrations.find({ key: this.regKey }, function(err1, registration) {
      console.log('Reg.find()');
      console.log(registration[0]);
      db.Configurations.find({ type: registration[0].type }, function(err2, config) {
        console.log('Config.find()');
        console.log('config=' + config[0].user);
        self.sapConfig = 'test';
      });
    });
  }

  this.get_result = function() {
    return self.sapConfig;
  }
}
```

For your second snippet. You are trying to return a value from within your nested callback. Since nested functions are asyncronous, you cannot do that.

Here is how I like to return values from nested callbacks:

Ex2:

```
//Function example
var functionWithNested = function(done) {
  //Notice the done param. 
  //  It is going to be a function that takes the finished data once all our nested functions are done.

  function() {
    //Do things
    function() {
      //do more things
      done("resultHere"); //finished. pass back the result.
    }();//end of 2nd nested function
  }(); //end of 1st nested function
};

//Calling the function
functionWithNested(function(result) {
  //Callback
  console.log(result); //resultHere
})
```

Here is your code using that example:

```
"use strict";

var mongojs = require('mongojs'); // MongoDB API wrapper

module.exports = function(regKey, done) {

  // Read SAP connection information from our MONGO db
  var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost/MIM', ['Configurations', 'Registrations']);

  db.Registrations.find({ key: regKey }, function(err1, registration) {
    console.log('Reg.find()');
    console.log(registration[0]);
    db.Configurations.find({ type: registration[0].type }, function(err2, config) {
      console.log('Config.find()');
      console.log('config=' + config[0].user);
      done(config[0].user);
    });
  });
}

//Then wherever you call the above function use this format
// if config is the name of the function export above...

new Config().(regKey, function(result){

    console.log(result); //config[0].user value
})
```

Lots and lots of code, but I hope you were able to follow it. Let me know if you have any more questions! Cheers.

Comment: Excellent! Worked like a charm and now that you explained it, it makes perfect sense. Do you know why the other snippet was returning "undefined", i.e., why the **return** statement didn't work as expected?

Comment: Glad it made sense to you. For your return statement issue: You can't return a value from within a nested callback. Ill add another example of how I like to return my values from nested callbacks. Just gimme a few :)

Comment: Yes! Perfect! It makes complete sense. I wasn't thinking "asynchronously". Excellent information. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ishmael Your welcome. Please mark my answer as the solution :) Good luck with your development :)